# Calendário em PHP / HTML - Como quebrar tabela em 7 colunas

Tags: php, html

Estou tentando construir um calendário em HTML e PHP, mas estou com algumas dificuldades, uma delas é, como eu quebro a tabela em sete colunas em um for invés de colocar todos os dias da semana em linha reta?

Segue meu código até o momento.

```
<?php

function diasMeses(){
$retorno = array();

for ($i=1; $i <= 12 ; $i++) { 
    $retorno[$i] = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $i, date('Y'));

}

return $retorno;
}

function quebraMesEmDias($array, $mes)
{
$qtdDias = $array[$mes];
$retorno = array();
for ($i=1; $i <=$qtdDias ; $i++) { 
    array_push($retorno, $i);
}

return $retorno;
}


?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />
<script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<table border="2">

<?php 
$qtd_dias_mes = diasMeses();
// Inserindo manualmente o mês a ser mostrado
$numMes = 2;
$array_mes_desejado = quebraMesEmDias($qtd_dias_mes, $numMes);

foreach ($array_mes_desejado as $indice => $mes) {

?>
    <td>
          <?php 

             echo $mes;

            ?>
    </td>
<?php } ?>


</table>
```

Desde já, agradeço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá! Irei passar a forma como eu construo um calendário. Peço desculpa por não montar com base no seu, mas veja os comentários específico para cada parte da lógica do código que responde sua questão em relação a quebra da tabela em 7 colunas.

```
<?php

function my_calendar($month,$year) {

     // Cria uma matriz contendo abreviações de dias da semana.
     $daysOfWeek = array('Dom.','Seg.','Terç.','Qua.','Qui.','Sex.','Sáb.'); 

     // Qual é o primeiro dia do mês em questão?
     $firstDayOfMonth = mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year);

     // Quantos dias este mês contém?
     $numberDays = date('t',$firstDayOfMonth);

     // Recupere algumas informações sobre o primeiro dia do mês em questão.
     $dateComponents = getdate($firstDayOfMonth);

     // Qual é o valor do índice (0-6) do primeiro dia do mês em questão.
     $dayOfWeek = $dateComponents['wday'];

     //cabeçalho

     $calendar = "<table class='calendar'>";
     $calendar .= "<caption>$year</caption>";
     $calendar .= "<tr>";

     // Cria os cabeçalhos do calendário

     foreach($daysOfWeek as $day) {
          $calendar .= "<th class='header'>$day</th>";
     } 

     /* Cria o resto do calendário
        Inicia o contador de dias, começando com o 1º. */

     $currentDay = 1;

     $calendar .= "</tr><tr>";

     /* A variável $dayOfWeek é usada para
        garantir que o calendário
        display consiste em exatamente 7 colunas. */

     if ($dayOfWeek > 0) { 
          $calendar .= "<td colspan='$dayOfWeek'>&nbsp;</td>"; 
     }

     $month = str_pad($month, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

     while ($currentDay <= $numberDays) {

          //Sétima coluna (sábado) alcançada. Comece uma nova linha.

          if ($dayOfWeek == 7) {

               $dayOfWeek = 0;
               $calendar .= "</tr><tr>";

          }

          $currentDayRel = str_pad($currentDay, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

          $date = "$year-$month-$currentDayRel";

          $calendar .= "<td class='day' rel='$date'>$currentDay</td>";

          //Incremento 
          $currentDay++;
          $dayOfWeek++;

     }


     // Preencha a linha da última semana do mês, se necessário

     if ($dayOfWeek != 7) { 

          $remainingDays = 7 - $dayOfWeek;
          $calendar .= "<td colspan='$remainingDays'>&nbsp;</td>"; 

     }

     $calendar .= "</tr>";

     $calendar .= "</table>";

     return $calendar;

}

?> 

<?php

$dateComponents = getdate();

$month = $dateComponents['mon'];                 
$year = $dateComponents['year'];

echo "Mês corrente ". PHP_EOL;
echo my_calendar($month,$year);

echo "<hr /> Seleção manual do mês de fevereiro do ano 2018 ". PHP_EOL;
echo my_calendar(2,2018);

?>
```

Comment: Vou testar o código, mto obrigado!